# No data values after raster export (force RGB)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, export, rgb

I have a problem when I export a raster (DEM here after). I use the same parameters as the original with "Use renderer" and "Force RGB".

[image]
But the RGB contains no data values. And obviously, I don't want this.

Do you know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You can leave the no data value to blank while exporting.

Comment: I don't have no data value before exporting. The raster I have to export to RGB is a raster of elevation.

Comment: And the software is?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.3 (15 characters)